# Traducción del verbo "ablate"

Tags: traducción

He estado buscando por Internet alguna traducción al español del inglés "ablate", sin poder encontrar ninguna. Sé que frases como "ablation shield" se traduciría como "escudo de ablación", pero ¿cómo podría traducir "the heatshield is ablating"?

Comment: I think you mean _the heatshield is being ablated_. As the definition @Carlos quotes in his answer _ablate_ is a transitive verb in English.

Answer (score 3):

En el Merriam-Webster puedes ver que *[ablate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ablate)* significa:

> to remove or destroy especially by cutting, abrading, or evaporating

Por su parte, *[ablation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ablation)* es:

> loss of a part (as ice from a glacier or the outside of a nose cone) by melting or vaporization

Por tanto, no es necesario buscar en español un verbo que corresponda con "ablación", puedes decir sencillamente que el escudo térmico se está...

- desintegrando
- evaporando
- destruyendo
- derritiendo
- dañando
- etc.

Comment: http://dle.rae.es/?id=068qwN0 Ablación también es una palabra en español. Lo traducen como extirpación, así que extirpar sería una traducción correcta.

Comment: @SergioTx según en qué contextos. La pregunta hace referencia a un escudo térmico, y ahí no veo esa traducción.